# Hitting REST Feature services via console app (C#)

Tags: arcobjects, enterprise-geodatabase, c#, .net, feature-service

I have a console app that currently leverages arcObjects through a desktop license.

We are going to need it to transport data to and from a traditional versioned gdb to and from feature services along with a few other tasks.

ArcObjects is required, and the machine I’m running it on should have arcGIS desktop on it (not sure about pro or server).

What would be the recommended approach to hit the Feature services to read data and post edits too (and trying to minimize cost)?